# What does browserConnectionEnabled capability mean?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I wonder what does browserConnectionEnabled capability param means. It is used in in chromedriver http://code.google.com/p/chromium/source/search?q=browserConnectionEnabled&origq=browserConnectionEnabled&btnG=Search+Trunk and is explained as "Whether the session can query for the browser's connectivity and disable it if desired.". But I dont understand what does it realy do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's used in mobile drivers where the state of connectivity can be manipulated (e.g. for testing offline web apps). As far as I know his is only available in the Android driver at the moment.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? Are there issues to get this supported on desktop browsers? I want to test my web app when the internet goes down on a web browser.